# Solve heat equation with $w(x,0)=\exp(-|x|)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I've been working on this problem for a while now, for context, I'm allowed to solved using Fourier integral, transform or series, but the most recent topic was the Laplace transform which is the method I've been trying.

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\ (-\infty <x<\infty ,\ t > 0)\\
u(x,0)=\exp(-|x|)
\end{cases}$$

The transformed equation results in $$ sW-w(x,0)=\frac{d^2W}{dx^2} \to W''-sW=-\exp(-|x|)$$ With what I've learned, this should be solved by proposing a general solution combined linearly with a particular solution $$ W(x,s) = W_c(x,s) + W_p(x,s) $$ I have solved the homogeneous problem to $$ W_c(x,s) =C_1\exp(\sqrt(s)x)+C_2\exp(-\sqrt(s)x) $$ but how can I propose a particular solution?

Thanks in adance.

Comment: I think the Fourier transform looks more promising. And that it would be simpler to first solve the case where $w(x,0)$ equals $e^x$ for $x<0$ and zero for $x>0$. Once you find that solution, you can just add it to its mirror image (change $x$ to $-x$) to obtain the solution that you seek here.